# TD element's width doesn't apply to the grid

Tags: html, css, razor

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">


<table id="grid" style="float: left; position: relative">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width ="310px"data-field="FileName">File Name
            </th>
            <th  width ="290px"data-field="ID">File Identifier
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr >
                <td  class="idRank" >
                    @item.FileName
                </td>
                <td  class="idRank2"  >
                    @item.ID
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

I use external css

```
table#grid.k-focusable td.idRank
         { width:310px;
          }
```

but it doesnt apply and not able to wident by 310 px, any idea ?
what other css method to do for me to get that applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are giving same **width (310px)** to your first column at  and another at **(290px)**;
you have to give them according to the width of table as you deserve

Comment: well, i want the <th> has different width, and the<td> have the width according to the <th >you know

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of Class `.k-focusable` in 
`table#grid.k-focusable td.idRank
{ width:310px;}`

Due to this `.k-focusable` width is not being set.

Instead try

```
table#grid .idRank
{ width:310px;}
```